# Allocation of memory with LE routines

Tags: cobol, mainframe

At
[Allocation of Memory in Variable-Length Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000777/allocation-of-memory-in-variable-length-tables)
NealB mentioned LE routines to allocate/deallocate memory in a non-CICS COBOL program.

I'd very much like to know how this is done: how the LE routine is called. (I'm familiar with the LINKAGE SECTION and with SET ADDRESS.)

Since I have no access to an IBM mainframe at the moment - meaning no access to online documentation - some code snippets could enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

In an LE environment, you would call CEEGTST and CEEFRST to get and free storage.

They both take a 12-byte result token as the first parameter -- if you pass null, LE will abend for you on a failure.

The second parameter is the address.

In the case of CEEGTST, you also pass a third, length, parameter.

Example to allocate:

```
Call 'CEEGTST' using
  omitted
  address of some-linkage-item
  length of some-linkage-item
End-Call
```

Example to free:

```
Call 'CEEFRST' using
  omitted
  address of some-linkage-item
End-Call
```

Comment: I don't think your examples and explanation are correct. See [CEEGTST--Get heap storage](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA3160/2.2.5.38?DT=20050629120436) - First parameter is the Heap Id, third is the 12 byte result token. Passing a zero as the first parameter requests memory allocation from the user heap. Similar for [CEEFRST--Free heap storage ](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA3160/2.2.5.32?DT=20050629120436) last (second) parameter is the result token.

Comment: True, I mixed the heapid and fc parms up.  The correct signature for CEEGTST is CEEGTST(heap,size,address,fc) and you can omit FC if you want a failure to cause an abend.

Comment: Also, the correct signature for CEEFRST is (address, fc).  Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all IBM product and technical documentation is available on the internet.
It can be a bit of a chore to sort out but have a look at 
[Book Manger](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/library)

To answer your specific question, the

[Language Environment Programming Reference](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA31A0/CCONTENTS?DT=20090608042151) tells you just about everything you will
ever need to know about LE. The memory management routines you may want to expore are: CEEGTST
(allocate memory) and CEEFRST (free memory).

The following is a bit long but it is a complete IBM Enterprise COBOL program that does some simple
memory management stuff using LE.

```
  ***************************************************
  **                                               **
  ** DEMONSTRATION FOR LINKED LIST HANDLING        **
  **                                               **
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. LINKLST.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  RET-CDE                 PIC 9(3).
   01  HEAD-OF-LIST            POINTER.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01  LINK                              GLOBAL.
       02 DATA-PART            PIC 9(4).
       02 NEXT-PTR             POINTER.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       CALL "BULDLST" USING HEAD-OF-LIST,
                            RET-CDE
       IF RET-CDE = ZERO THEN
          CALL "SHOWLST" USING HEAD-OF-LIST
          CALL "FREELST" USING HEAD-OF-LIST
          IF HEAD-OF-LIST = NULL THEN
             DISPLAY "LIST HAS BEEN FREED."
          END-IF
       END-IF
       GOBACK
       .
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID BULDLST.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  I                       PIC 9(4).
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 HEAD-OF-LIST             POINTER.
   01 RET-CDE                  PIC 9(3).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING HEAD-OF-LIST, RET-CDE.
   MAINLINE SECTION.
       CALL "MEMALOC" USING BY REFERENCE HEAD-OF-LIST,
                            BY CONTENT   LENGTH OF LINK,
                            BY REFERENCE RET-CDE
       IF RET-CDE = ZERO THEN
          SET ADDRESS OF LINK TO HEAD-OF-LIST
          PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
                    UNTIL I > 4
                       OR RET-CDE > ZERO
             MOVE I TO DATA-PART OF LINK
             CALL "MEMALOC" USING BY REFERENCE NEXT-PTR OF LINK,
                                  BY CONTENT   LENGTH   OF LINK,
                                  BY REFERENCE RET-CDE
             IF RET-CDE = ZERO THEN
                SET ADDRESS OF LINK TO NEXT-PTR OF LINK
             END-IF
          END-PERFORM
          IF RET-CDE = ZERO THEN
             MOVE I TO DATA-PART OF LINK
             SET NEXT-PTR        OF LINK TO NULL
          END-IF
       END-IF
       GOBACK
       .
   END PROGRAM BULDLST.
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID SHOWLST.
   DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 HEAD-OF-LIST             POINTER.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING HEAD-OF-LIST.
   MAINLINE SECTION.
       SET ADDRESS OF LINK TO HEAD-OF-LIST
       PERFORM UNTIL ADDRESS OF LINK = NULL
           DISPLAY DATA-PART
           SET ADDRESS OF LINK TO NEXT-PTR OF LINK
       END-PERFORM
       GOBACK
       .
   END PROGRAM SHOWLST.
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID FREELST.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 NXT-PTR                  POINTER.
   01 RET-CDE                  PIC 9(3).
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 HEAD-OF-LIST             POINTER.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING HEAD-OF-LIST.
   MAINLINE SECTION.
       MOVE ZERO TO RET-CDE
       PERFORM UNTIL HEAD-OF-LIST = NULL OR
                     RET-CDE NOT = ZERO
           SET ADDRESS OF LINK TO HEAD-OF-LIST
           SET NXT-PTR TO NEXT-PTR OF LINK
           CALL "MEMFREE" USING HEAD-OF-LIST, RET-CDE
           SET HEAD-OF-LIST TO NXT-PTR
       END-PERFORM
       GOBACK
       .
   END PROGRAM FREELST.
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID MEMALOC COMMON PROGRAM.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  HEAPID                  PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   01  FC.
       02  CONDITION-TOKEN-VALUE.
       COPY  CEEIGZCT.
           03  CASE-1-CONDITION-ID.
               04  SEVERITY    PIC S9(4) BINARY.
               04  MSG-NO      PIC S9(4) BINARY.
           03  CASE-2-CONDITION-ID
                     REDEFINES CASE-1-CONDITION-ID.
               04  CLASS-CODE  PIC S9(4) BINARY.
               04  CAUSE-CODE  PIC S9(4) BINARY.
           03  CASE-SEV-CTL    PIC X.
           03  FACILITY-ID     PIC XXX.
       02  I-S-INFO            PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 PTR-TO-MEM               POINTER.
   01 NBR-OF-BYTES             PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   01 RET-CDE                  PIC 9(3).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING PTR-TO-MEM, NBR-OF-BYTES, RET-CDE.
       MOVE 0 TO HEAPID
       CALL "CEEGTST" USING HEAPID,
                            NBR-OF-BYTES,
                            PTR-TO-MEM,
                            FC
       IF CEE000 OF FC  THEN
           MOVE ZERO TO RET-CDE
       ELSE
           DISPLAY "CEEGTST FAILED WITH: " MSG-NO OF FC
           MOVE 1 TO RET-CDE
           SET PTR-TO-MEM TO NULL
       END-IF
       GOBACK.
   END PROGRAM MEMALOC.
  ***************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID MEMFREE COMMON PROGRAM.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  HEAPID                  PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   01  FC.
       02  CONDITION-TOKEN-VALUE.
       COPY  CEEIGZCT.
           03  CASE-1-CONDITION-ID.
               04  SEVERITY    PIC S9(4) BINARY.
               04  MSG-NO      PIC S9(4) BINARY.
           03  CASE-2-CONDITION-ID
                     REDEFINES CASE-1-CONDITION-ID.
               04  CLASS-CODE  PIC S9(4) BINARY.
               04  CAUSE-CODE  PIC S9(4) BINARY.
           03  CASE-SEV-CTL    PIC X.
           03  FACILITY-ID     PIC XXX.
       02  I-S-INFO            PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 PTR-TO-MEM               POINTER.
   01 RET-CDE                  PIC 9(3).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING PTR-TO-MEM, RET-CDE.
       MOVE 0 TO HEAPID
       CALL "CEEFRST" USING PTR-TO-MEM,
                            FC
       IF CEE000 OF FC  THEN
           MOVE ZERO TO RET-CDE
       ELSE
           DISPLAY "CEEFRST FAILED WITH: " MSG-NO OF FC
           MOVE 1 TO RET-CDE
       END-IF
       GOBACK.
   END PROGRAM MEMFREE.
   END PROGRAM LINKLST.
  ***************************************************
```

The program writes:

`0001
    0002
    0003
    0004
    0005
    LIST HAS BEEN FREED.`

Not terribly exciting but does demonstrate how to string a few things together.